# c# windows form treeview select node name matching user key entry

Tags: c#, treeview, focus

I guess I have missed one of the treeview control settings. I need to let the user type in a set of characters then select the node with a name that matches the typed word. At the moment the treeview only selects on one character. For example, there are two parent nodes with text that start with "1001" and "1528". When the user quickly types 1528 , the 1001 node is selected - and not the node that starts with 1528.

[image showing properties of the treeview control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKoA1.png)

[youtube showing action user enters 1528 but only 1 is used - the first character typed](https://youtu.be/nr0W4qF31Mc)

Comment: can you show us the code which you have used

Comment: Only one event used - afterselect - I use that to identify the selected node . Properties of the treeview control are shown here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/4egzrde1sg8qoju/2018-05-31-01.png?dl=0  and here is a video showing what happens, user types in 1528 which corresponds to the start text of one of the nodes , but only the first character typed is used in node selection "1" : https://youtu.be/nr0W4qF31Mc